# Composer Failing on New EC2 Instance (Elastic Beanstalk)

Tags: php, composer-php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I manage a several year old app for which I am not the original developer.

The site has been running on AWS EB since late 2014 - using laravel 4.

Today, AWS terminated my ec2 instance as the type of box is being retired. The new instance spawned without issue, but the app was not running.

When I try to deploy an version of theapp (via zip), I get the following error:

> [Instance: i-03441954f29775f02] Command failed on instance. Return
>   code: 1 Output:
>   [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/10_composer_install.sh]
>   command failed with error code 1:
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_composer_install.sh ++
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir +
>   EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=/var/app/ondeck + cd /var/app/ondeck + '[' -f
>   composer.json ']' + export COMPOSER_HOME=/root + COMPOSER_HOME=/root +
>   '[' -d vendor ']' ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config
>   optionsettings -n aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini -o
>   composer_options + PHP_COMPOSER_OPTIONS= + echo 'Found composer.json
>   file. Attempting to install vendors.' Found composer.json file.
>   Attempting to install vendors. + composer.phar install --no-ansi
>   --no-interaction [UnexpectedValueException] .

I, unfortunately, have not been much of a PHP developer for the past 4-5 years, so I am a little confused as to where to start. It seems like an issue with the file itself, this is what I have:

```
{
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
  "license": "MIT",
  "require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "zizaco/confide": "~4.0@dev",
    "dollar/generators": "dev-master",
    "anahkiasen/former": "dev-master",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0",
    "rhumsaa/uuid": "~2.7",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "1.*",
    "nesbot/Carbon": "*",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "1.*",
    "mandrill/mandrill": "1.0.*",
    "barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "0.1.x",
    "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "0.12.0",
    "davibennun/laravel-raygun": "dev-master",
    "dchesterton/marketo-rest-api": "^0.0.5"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "app/commands",
      "app/controllers",
      "app/models",
      "app/database/migrations",
      "app/database/seeds",
      "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "php artisan clear-compiled",
      "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "php artisan clear-compiled",
      "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
      "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

Beyond this, I ma not sure if there's something i need to do to the EC2 box itself. I will say that the server has been regenerated in the past - probably not for 2 years or so, without issue.

These are the server specs from EB.

64bit Amazon Linux 2014.09 v1.0.9 running PHP 5.5

Comment: try some primitive package like (single sdk), to isolate the problem. If the service works, it means the composer config is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

this issue happened to me as well, after digging deep into the `/var/log/eb-activity.log` (you have to ssh into your instance to access this log file) i found out that some packages in my composer.json were requiring PHP version 7.3 and in my  Instance, I had PHP 7.2.

What I did to resolve this was to downgrade the dependences (laravel-websockets in my case) from 1.3 to 1.2 because currently PHP 7.3 is not supported by the elastic beanstalk.

But you can also upgrade your PHP version if this is the case.

In order to really know what is the problem, it is better to visit the log file  `/var/log/eb-activity.log`